# Can I add or update a new variable after render in django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've been trying to add or update a variable in the templete before the first render. I have an Ajax request that sends a POST request which works fine, but when I tried to return the new variable, `destinations`, to the same page/template, index.html, it doesn't appear.

How do I fix this behavior?

view.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dayset = request.POST.get('the_point')
        dest = Destination(get_cons(dayset))
        destinations = dest.latlond()
        context = {'destinations': destinations}
        render(request, 'index.html', context)
    else:
        objan = Antennas(antenas)
        antposition = objan.getAntennas()
        context = {'antposition': antposition}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Temple index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DAKARmob</title>
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "scripts/main.js" %}"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
{% for pos in antposition %}
var marker = L.marker([{{pos.1}}, {{pos.2}}], {
  icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
      'marker-color': '#b9e841'
  }),
  draggable: false
}).on('click', onAnte);
antenas[{{pos.0}}] = [{{pos.1}}, {{pos.2}}];
cluster_ant.addLayer(marker);
{% endfor %}
map.addLayer(cluster_ant);

function onAnte(e) {
  var latl = this.getLatLng();
  var aux = [latl.lat,latl.lng];
  var result = getKeysForValue(antenas, aux);
  new_point(result[0]);


 function new_point(id) {
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url : "/", // the endpoint
            type : "POST", // http method
            data : { the_point : id }, // data sent with the post request
            success : function(res) {
                console.log("success"); // another sanity check
            }
        });

  }
  // OTHER FUNCTIONS FOR THE FUNCTION OF AJAX AND DJANGO 

</script>
<div style="position:absolute; top:900px; left:10px; ">
{{ destinations }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your template code?

Comment: If you are sending it through ajax, you do not want to re-render all the page. I recommend you to return a JSON Response, and get data from this JSON via javascript in the template.

You will not be able to get {{ destinations }}, unless you refresh the whole page.

Comment: I'd rather not refresh the page. @Celeo

Comment: post your AJAX request code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), which you can use to return the new variable as json to your ajax function, which can then be used to set that variable in your template.

Comment: Thx I already solved it with JsonResponse. Returning the response to the ajax function. And show it into the template. Thanks again.